# Python library for time with no limit on hours for duration calculation

Tags: python

Is there python built-in class in standard library for time, where there's no limit for hours? In datetime.time hours should be < 24. If there's no such class in standard library, is there external library with no limit of this kind?

I need time object with no connection to date, just for time duration calculation or at least time object that can be created from "201:40:23".

Comment: What about the python [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) module?

Comment: Have you tried `datetime.timedelta`?

Comment: Thank you, timedelta seems fine. Although, timedelta lacks hours and minutes return methods, so I might need to extend this class